# Documentation on Guardian project ffmpeg android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I got the Gaurdian Project FFMPEG android java from the following link

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

Is there any good documents available to use the library for code. Its difficult to use without documentation. Plz help me.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get it work.

First, download the guardian project ffmpeg [library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects):

Then import it in eclipse. (no need to follow their Build Procedure, with the NDK just import their project in eclipse directly)

Then right click on your Main project (not the library project) -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add

Then, use it this way :

```
  File fileTmp = context.getActivity().getCacheDir();
  File fileAppRoot = new File(context.getActivity().getApplicationInfo().dataDir);

  FfmpegController fc = new FfmpegController(fileTmp, fileAppRoot);


  final Clip out = new Clip("compiled.mp4");


  fc.concatAndTrimFilesMP4Stream(videos, out, true, false,  new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {

        @Override
        public void shellOut(String shellLine) {
            System.out.println("MIX> " + shellLine);
        }

        @Override
        public void processComplete(int exitValue) {

            if (exitValue != 0) {
                System.err.println("concat non-zero exit: " + exitValue);
                Log.d("ffmpeg","Compilation error. FFmpeg failed");
            } else {
                if(new File(out.path).exists()) {
                    Log.d("ffmpeg","Success file:"+out.path);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

With an `ArrayList<Clip>` of videos you want to concatenate.

Comment: So, when you created "compiled.mp4", where did it save the file? Is there a best practice that you've found as to where to actually move these files to? SDCard?

Comment: The best practice (as far as I know) is to store everything in the app folder : myActivity.getFilesDir()

Comment: Cool, thanks. I only ask because I can't find the file produced. I'm wondering if it's deleted after creation, or has permissions issues writing, or who knows what. The file produced in your example above was saved in the root of myActivity.getFilesDir()?

Comment: For anyone reading this, I realized that if left unspecified, it will attempt to write to the root of the file system. adb logcat revealed this with the "permission denied" message. Once I wrote to context.getActivity().getCacheDir(), it worked.

Comment: I imported the guardian project and I can access all the functions etc but when I try to run your example code I get some errors * . I also don't know how to fill in your `videos` argument. Any advice on how I can test it some more? Error: [error code](http://pastebin.com/2urLj3Db)            And this is what the `System.out.println` says: 05-05 18:48:52.708: I/System.out(7970): MIX> ffmpeg -y -i /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20140331_132211.mp4 -an -strict -2 /data/data/com.denayer.ovsr/cache/0-trim.mp4

Comment: videos is a ArrayList<Clip>. About your errors, I have to admit I don't see the problem. can you paste your whole code ? (are your sure of the paths of your videos and out clip? )

Comment: @Taiko are you using NDK revision 9?

Comment: @intrepidkarthi you don't need NDK :-) They have ready-made builds. Just download their zip https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/archive/master.zip open it, then import it in eclipse. Then Include it as a Library project in your main project : http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

Comment: @Taiko Yes. I am also doing the same. Look at this question whether you can give any suggestion for my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533794/issue-in-concatenating-two-video-files-using-ffmpeg

Comment: @Taiko do you have any working sample on non rooted real device?

Comment: Getting error `Attempt to invoke virtual method char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray() on a null object reference` at the line `fc.concatAndTrimFilesMP4Stream(listVideos, clipOut, true, false, new ShellCallback() {` Any idea what could be the problem?