# FFmpeg fails to be built for android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm trying to build FFmpeg for android, everything works just fine until the build of `build_android.sh`, I get at the end :

```
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ../ffmpeg-build/armeabi/lib
make: *** [install-libavresample-shared] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ../ffmpeg-build/armeabi/lib
make: *** [install-libavutil-shared] Error 2
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ../ffmpeg-build/armeabi/lib
make: *** [install-libswresample-shared] Error 2
```

I've been inspecting this for a while but couldn't figure out where the problem is..

Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ...This is to run ffmpeg commands on android armeabi and armv7-a devices.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660043/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-is-unable-to-create-an-executable-compile-ffmpeg-for/13244551#13244551)